Sales history of an ASIN
Is there a way to get the past/recent history of sales of a listing in Amazon SP-API?
Eg. someting like --  given the ASIN, marketplace-ID and an x number of days, the call would return how many of that ASIN has been sold within the last x days in that marketplace-ID.
Is this possible? In which model?
I'm using the Java SP-API, if that matters
I doubt there is-- kept looking and looking, and there's no such "manual" feature on sellercentral(?) But don't want to miss out. I also appreciate if you'd verify that no such feature.
TIA.
//=====================
The ASIN I'll be querying is any/given ASIN, not one I'm selling.

Before I answer, I want to understand if what you are looking for is for an ASIN that you currently sell or for a generic ASIN.

@Marconline a generic ASIN. i know how to get sales data of my own ASIN.

No, there is no way to get that kind of information for an ASIN you are not selling, as far as I know.
The best you can get is the Sales Rank which you can obtain by performing a getCatalogItem call, and setting the includedData parameter to salesRanks.
For those who are interested in getting precious insights on ASIN currently being sold by the account which is making the call, the Sales and Traffic Business Report, which contains exactly what is requested.
